# How is it possible that a Button is pressed even though it is behind an ImageView?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton

I have an imageview with a button under it, and yet if a press the imageview the button beneath is pressed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: By default, image views don't block touches because they have `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to false.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I just don't want the button to be pressed when there's the imageview above it. Why does this even happen?

Comment: Because of image view has userInteractionEnabled NO by default ios looks for another view that has user interactions.
You can find more at [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW2)

Comment: and this answer is an answer to your question `How can I fix this?`

Comment: i think it is also possible to block all behind the image with `myImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`?